# Simplest nginx reverse proxy to another container on same host gives 502 Bad Gateway / connection refused

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, docker

Totally stuck now.

This is what I have. I build and run a simple HTML page in nginx on port 8080 (I eventually want to run a Java tomcat app when I've figured this out).

This is on Windows 10 with Docker 17.09 and nginx 1.13

This is the config:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
COPY static-html /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

and the config:

```
$ cat nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /dev/stdout warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /dev/stdout  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Run it like this:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:80 --name dummy --rm dummy-nginx
```

Responds nicely to `curl`:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.13.7
Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 16:46:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 101
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Nov 2017 16:24:39 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5a1edf47-65"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<head>
  <title>oh yeah</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Absolutely</h1>
  <p>did this work?</p>
</body>
```

So that all works fine. This is the same stuff for the reverse proxy which is the part that fails:

**Reverse proxy Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY apt-proxy.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d
COPY nginx_signing.key /etc/apt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y install gnupg gnupg2 gnupg1
RUN apt-key add /etc/apt/nginx_signing.key
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install net-tools
EXPOSE 10040
CMD ["nginx"]
```

(I put those extra tools in there to try to help diagnose this)

**Reverse proxy nginx.conf**

```
daemon off;
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
error_log /dev/stdout debug;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    upstream myapp {
        server localhost:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 10040;

        location / {
            proxy_pass $scheme://myapp;
            proxy_redirect default;
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }    
}
```

I heavily suspect the whole problem is just a minor error in there somewhere (banging head against wall).

**Command line to start up the reverse proxy**

This includes a bit of the logging with the error from nginx, and the access_log item which I also piped to /dev/stdout.

```
$ docker run -p 10040:10040 --name rproxy --rm we1p202420008.cloud.registry(example).com:11095/rproxy
2017/11/30 16:55:20 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2017/11/30 16:55:20 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.13.7
2017/11/30 16:55:20 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18)
2017/11/30 16:55:20 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 4.9.49-moby
2017/11/30 16:55:20 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2017/11/30 16:55:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2017/11/30 16:55:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 5
2017/11/30 16:55:25 [error] 5#5: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/", host: "localhost:10040"
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2017:16:55:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "curl/7.56.1"
2017/11/30 16:55:25 [info] 5#5: *1 client 172.17.0.1 closed keepalive connection
```

That error is logged when I try to access the dummy website thro the r-proxy like this:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:10040
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: nginx/1.13.7
Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 18:05:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 173
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.7</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if there is nothing obvious in the config I've just posted and it really isn't just my stupidity, then there is some baffling stuff which I can't get any further with. For instance, when I run `curl` inside my reverse proxy instance:

`docker exec rproxy curl -i http://localhost:8080`

it gives me the corporate firewall's blocked content result:

> The website http://localhost/ that you
>   are trying to access is currently categorised as Uncategorized URLs< and has been deemed to be
>   potentially unsafe or unsuitable for browsing.

Comment: I think the rproxy nginx is trying to connect to 8080 on itself, localhost, and not the hosts "localhost". It would have to proxy_pass to an address that reaches the other container. Check The IP address docker has assigned to the "dummy" container.

Comment: @mjb2kmn Agreed, the docker container will have an IP address of its own, the java app will be on the bridged address of the host (if I remember correctly).

Comment: So I should put the dummy app's FQDN in the reverse proxy nginx config?

Comment: Not really sure I understand, unless this is actually really difficult testing it with `curl http://localhost` on the command line

Answer (score 3):

Using **`bridge`** as the magic key word, I finally started getting the search engine results I needed.

The comment on the question pointed out the issue: nginx was just forwarding requests to `localhost:8080` internally within its own container, rather than the `host:ports` where the other docker containers are found.

I checked around and lots of people are writing the FQDNs of their proxied servers into their `nginx.conf`, which I didn't want to since I figured it might get overcomplicated when the build populates the configuration files for each environment.

So from [Accessing host machine from within docker container](https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248/5) and [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks) I learnt about `docker network` today and implemented the following to give my dev environment a unique and unchanging host ip.

In my `nginx.conf` for the reverse proxy, I have `proxy_pass http://myapp:8080` where `myapp` will be the docker container name I give the proxied app.

Then I create the user-defined bridge network:

`docker network create -d bridge myapp-net`

*I don't yet understand why the default docker bridge network won't work.*

And then I launch the containers, attaching them to the `myapp-net`:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 --network=myapp-net --name myapp --rm myregistry:11095/myapp`

`docker run -p 10040:443 --network=myapp-net --name rproxy --rm myregistry:11095/myapp-rproxy`

and it works.

I'm working on my Windows workstation and I figured writing the real external host FQDN into `nginx.conf` would require a new environment definition for each workstation, but with `myapp` in the conf file instead, it removes the dependency on the host name or IP.